# How do I export a folder to a subnet using NFS in FreeBSD 9.0

Tags: freebsd, nfs

The following NFS exports file does not work on FreeBSD 9.0.  How should I be specifying that I wish to share with the whole subnet?

```
mybox# cat /etc/exports 
 /storage/build 10.10.0.0/24(rw,no_root_squash)
```

Error from syslog:

```
mountd[1133]: bad exports list line /storage/build 
10.10.0.0/24(rw,no_root_squash)
```

/etc/rc.conf

```
rpcbind_enable="YES"
nfs_server_enable="YES"
mountd_flags="-r"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax isn't compatible with the FreeBSD implementation. Try this:

```
/storage/build -maproot=root -network 10.10.0 -mask 255.255.255.0
```

The `-maproot=root` option has the same meaning as `no_root_squash` in more Linux-centric implementations (it maps `root` on the client side to `root` on the server side). By default, FreeBSD nfs mounts are read/write, so you don't need to indicate it explicitly. Together, the `-network` and `-mask` options here tell the nfs server to allow mount requests from the 10.10.0/24 network. Alternatively, you can use CIDR notation (thanks to @Craig Sanders for pointing it out) and omit the `-mask` option.

Take a look at the `exports` manpage on your FreeBSD system. It goes into quite a bit of detail, and has several examples.

Comment: CIDR works according to the man page I linked to: `[...] The third case is specified by the flag -network=netname[/prefixlength] and optionally -mask=netmask.`  might be new to FreeBSD 9.x....dunno.

Comment: You're right - CIDR is supported. I'd never spotted that before. I'll edit my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'll try it out and mark the answer.  I am learning that googling for advice with FreeBSD is not the best answer, looking at the manual pages is.  There are just too many keywords in common with alternate implementations.

Comment: @JonnyRo - indeed! But it's not all bad - the FreeBSD documentation (handbook and man pages) is generally very good.

Answer (score 0):

There is a documentation available for exporting folders using NFS. You can have a look at this link : http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/hp-ux/man4/exports.4.html . This may be of some help to you .

" File /etc/exports describes the directories that can be exported to NFS clients."

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a Linux style /etc/exports.  FreeBSD's format is significantly different.

See http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=exports&sektion=5

You probably want something like:

```
/storage/build -network=10.10.0.0/24 -maproot=0
```